# Named Entity Recognition using Keras and Tensorflow - Overfitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write a  Named Entity Recognition model using Keras and Tensorflow.

I am training on a data that is has (Person,Products,Location,Others). 
Amongst these entities, the dataset is imbalanced with "Others" entity being a majority class.

As a result when I run predictions on my neural network with I am getting results that are biased to the the "Others" entity.. I want to know how to reduce the model from overfitting. Any approaches? I am sharing code for your reference.

## TRAINING PHASE

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, 
precision_recall_fscore_support

raw = open('taggedcontent.txt', 'r').readlines()

all_x = []
point = []
for line in raw:
stripped_line = line.strip().split(' ')
point.append(stripped_line)
if line == '\n':
    all_x.append(point[:-1])
    point = []
all_x = all_x[:-1]

lengths = [len(x) for x in all_x]
print ('Input sequence length range: ', max(lengths), min(lengths))

short_x = [x for x in all_x if len(x) < 3258]

X = [[c[0] for c in x] for x in short_x]

y = [[c[1] for c in y] for y in short_x]

all_text = [c for x in X for c in x]

words = list(set(all_text))
word2ind = {word: index for index, word in enumerate(words)}

ind2word = {index: word for index, word in enumerate(words)}
labels = list(set([c for x in y for c in x]))
label2ind = {label: (index + 1) for index, label in enumerate(labels)}
ind2label = {(index + 1): label for index, label in enumerate(labels)}
print ('Vocabulary size:', len(word2ind), len(label2ind))

maxlen = max([len(x) for x in X])
print ('Maximum sequence length:', maxlen)

def encode(x, n):
  result = np.zeros(n)
  result[x] = 1
return result

X_enc = [[word2ind[c] for c in x] for x in X]

max_label = max(label2ind.values()) + 1
y_enc = [[0] * (maxlen - len(ey)) + [label2ind[c] for c in ey] for ey in y]
y_enc = [[encode(c, max_label) for c in ey] for ey in y_enc]

X_enc = pad_sequences(X_enc, maxlen=maxlen)
y_enc = pad_sequences(y_enc, maxlen=maxlen)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_enc, y_enc, 
 test_size=11*32, train_size=45*32, random_state=42)
print ('Training and testing tensor shapes:', X_train.shape, X_test.shape, 
 y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

max_features = len(word2ind)
embedding_size = 128
hidden_size = 32
out_size = len(label2ind) + 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_size, input_length=maxlen, 
mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size)))model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

  batch_size = 32
  model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=10, 
  validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
    # serialize weights to HDF5
    model.save_weights("model.h5")
    print("Saved model to disk")
```

## VALIDATION PHASE

```
 x = "Google Microsoft Trump Pepsi"
 X = x..strip().split(' ')
 words = list(set(all_text))
 word2ind = {word: index for index, word in enumerate(words)}
 X_enc = [[word2ind[c] for c in x] for x in X]
 X_enc = pad_sequences(X_enc, maxlen=3258)
 pred = model.predict_classes(X_enc)
```

The predictions are completely biased to "Others" entity. Should I be creating a new word2ind in the predictions phase or should I be reusing it from the tra.ining phase. How can change this code to avoid overfitting and any suggestions.

 I also want to be using a Reinforcement or Online learning at the end of this model, so that Misclassified instances are reinforced into the model to achieve an accurate model. How can I use reinforcement learning in NLP use cases? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CRFLayer to the end of your model. you can find an implementation in Keras [here](https://github.com/Hironsan/keras-crf-layer).

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please significantly expand your answer. – *Reviewer*

Comment: Your answer is automatically flagged as low-quality, because it is very very short. Can you please extend on it?